# jQuery .load is not working with jade

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, pug

I am trying to load a jade page using  the jQuery `.load` function.
I have a div in index page where i want to load the other jade template when an anchor is clicked.

Jquery code is mentioned below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.navsub').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var page = $(this).attr('href');
            var pageout = $.get(page);
            if (page=='#')
                return false;
            else
            alert("working");
            $('#content_contain').load(pageout);
        });
});
```

and now rendering the page in app.js, rendering code in app.js is mentioned below

```
app.get('/somepage', function (req, res) {
    var some = res.render('somepage', { title: 'someotherpage' });
    res.send(some);
});
```

Now the question is how do i render the jade template which will be called when anchor will be clicked and call it inside a div.

The jQuery code above works fine if the page extension is `.html` or `.php`, but not with `.jade`.

Can someone explain why this doesn't work?
I'm using node.js and express.js.

Comment: Jade is server-side, Jquery is client-side so you might have issues there. The server should be rending the Jade as HTML then sending it to the client. It's also possible that Jade isn't in your node.js dependancies.

Comment: May I use nQuery rather than using jQuery or is there any possible way to render .jade page and call it through jQuery.

Comment: @Nuclearman please help me with this, what shouldi do now.?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with the page. Your server should render the Jade as HTML then send the HTML to the client which then works fine with jQuery. What you can't do is just send the client the .jade file as they won't know what to do with it. Alternative, if the Jade file is a relatively static page, you could compile the .jade file into an HTML file during development (this might be workable if you are using Jade pages). I can't say what is the best option for you or really with only a single line of code. It would help if you included the jade file and the rest of the script.

Comment: @Nuclearman please check, i have updated the question with code.

Comment: Please share your jade template. Also, have a look at jQuery's [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function. You don't need to do `$.get`, then `.load`. Then, `.load` taks a url as parameter, so you should `.load(page)` instead of `.load(pageout)`